# How to get camera intrinsics and extrinsics in UWP using Media Foundation

Tags: uwp, ms-media-foundation

According to MSDN, [MFSampleExtension_CameraExtrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mfsampleextension-cameraextrinsics) and [MFSampleExtension_PinholeCameraIntrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mfsampleextension-pinholecameraintrinsics) attributes are supported only in desktop apps.

How can I get the camera extrinsics and intrinsics in UWP apps using Media Foundation?

Comment: Hello, If you plan to get the camera's camera intrinsics information, you can use [MediaFrameSource.TryGetCameraIntrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframesource.trygetcameraintrinsics?view=winrt-19041) in [MediaFrameSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframesource?view=winrt-19041). For extrinsics information, UWP does not yet provide related APIs.